# Run function on specific key press

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to program a jquery script that does a fadeIn() on an element identified as myDiv when I press the x key.

```
function showKeyCode(e) {
   //alert( "keyCode for the key pressed: " + e.keyCode + "\n" );
   $if(e.keycode == 88){$("#myDiv").fadeIn();
}
```

Points to take note of. When I allow the alert x displays a key code of 88

This code does not work.

Comment: Actually, you would get a better response if you posted some code and did not straight out ask the community to write something for you.

Comment: Is the `}` after the `fadeIn();` missing in your original code too?

Comment: let me know if it works for you as well, or not

Answer (score 1):

This works when you press key "X":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mydiv = $('.mydiv');
    $(document).bind('keydown',function(e){
       if(e.keyCode == 88) {
          mydiv.fadeIn();
       }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TWm6r/

I used a class, but would give you no problem using an ID

Comment: The OP asked for the **x** key not Enter

Comment: @RubenInfante  that was the purpose of `console.log()`, but it seams that you couldn't notice that...

Comment: @user2090744 Well, if it works for you... please accept the answer